# Ruby on Rails - Multiparameter assignment and attr_accessor and 12_hour_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor

Ok, I'm slowly getting a grasp on this, but I need some more help.

I'm using a time_select in my view, therefore I'm dealing with a multiparameter assignment. Check.

```
<%= pt.time_select :time, :twelve_hour => true, :minute_step => 5 %>
```

BUT I'm doing the naughty thing and using it with an attribute that isn't in the database:

```
attr_accessor time
```

Therefore since it can't look at the db, it can't piece together what the multiparameter assignment is supposed to be and therefore I get the following error:

```
1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes
```

Thus I am using information I found [here](http://gabeodess.heroku.com/posts/14):

```
  composed_of :time,
            :class_name => 'DateTime',
            :mapping => [%w(DateTime to_s)],
            :constructor => Proc.new{ |item| item },
            :converter => Proc.new{ |item| item }
```

Other helpful links: [rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html) | [apidock.com](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of)

This remove the error, but now the issue is that the plugin I'm using doesn't function properly, I think. I am using [`http://code.google.com/p/rails-twelve-hour-time-plugin/`](http://code.google.com/p/rails-twelve-hour-time-plugin/). The goal being, I'm trying to get the time select to have 3 drop downs: `hh`:`mm` `am/pm`.

So the question is: how do I need to adjust my `composed_of method` in order for it to be properly converted by the plugin? OR is there a better method to this madness?

I'm not sure what mappers / constructors / converters I need. Right now the object keeps the hour and minute, except the hour isn't converted to 24 hour (which the plugin is supposed to take care of, I thought).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't follow the article properly. I should have been using the Time model.

```
  composed_of :time,
            :class_name => 'Time',
            :mapping => [%w(Time to_s)],
            :constructor => Proc.new{ |item| item },
            :converter => Proc.new{ |item| item }
```

Looks like this is a common problem. For more information about it check out this [link](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2675-support-for-multiparameter-attribute-assignment-on-virtual-attribute-writers). The suggestion given there is to do:

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  attr_accessor :arrival_time
  columns_hash["arrival_time"] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("arrival_time", nil, "time")
end
```

I'm still working out bugs, but I'll update this when I get something working.

Comment: `composed_of` does not works for me, same error as with attr_accessor. However, setting `columns_hash` works well, thanks!

Comment: The `columns_hash` fix almost worked for me but it was saving times in UTC and ignoring daylight savings. After spending 2 hours experimenting with `Time.zone.parse` and `.in_time_zone` I finally figured out the problem - changing the `sql_type` from `time` to `timestamp with timezone` made it work perfectly: `columns_hash["arrival_time"] = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new("arrival_time", nil, "timestamp with timezone")`. This is on a Rails project which uses PostgreSQL so YMMV.

Comment: I realise that I'm replying to a post which is over a year old, btw, but I thought I'd mention the time zone thing in case anyone else gets frustrated by it in future :)